# Github azure/arm-deploy actions fails when a new bicep version is available

Tags: github-actions, azure-bicep

The github action fails when using github action azure/arm-deploy to deploy a bicep template on a github hosted agent because bicep writes an output to stderr indicating there is a new version. The action fails as soon as something was send to stderr.

I have seen this behavior a couple of days back when bicep was upgraded from v0.13.1 to v0.14.6. Today I encounter the same when upgrading to v0.14.46. The only thing I was able to do at that time was waiting until the latest version of bicep was available (luckily it lasted less then a day before the hosted-agents were updated with the latest bicep version).

While trying more, I noticed that some action pipelines succeeded. This was probably because agents were getting updated and I was just lucky to have an agent with the latest bicep version.

Is there a way I can circumvent this? Can I deploy a bicep template even if the github hosted agent is not on the latest bicep version?

Following has been tried:

- I added a step in the pipeline to deploy a specific bicep version. This didn't seem to work; the bicep version available on the hosted agent was taken (making multiple runs resulted in a random Bicep version, depending on what's available on the agent).
- Setting failOnStdErr: false (property on azure/arm-deploy) had no effect and is not prefered because I want to be informed if a bicep deployment failed or not.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options, run any of these before the arm-deploy task.

1. Upgrade bicep in your workflow. Add:

   ```
   steps:
   - run: az bicep upgrade
   ```
2. Turn off update checking:

   ```
   steps:
   - run: az config set bicep.check_version=False
   ```
3. Don't let az pick the bicep from the path:

   ```
   steps:
   - run: az config set bicep.use_binary_from_path=false
   ```

Comment: As described, step 1 was tried before and didn't work out. I added step 2 and didn't have the issue ever since. Though I must say that I wasn't assigned a hosted agent anymore. Lets see what new bicep releases bring ...

Comment: Try adding: `az config set bicep.use_binary_from_path=false`

Comment: The command that worked for me was `az config set bicep.check_version=False`. `version_check` didn't work.

Comment: In that case the docs need an update: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bicep?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: See: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/26662

Comment: @jessehouwing why does this work and what does it do together with upgrade?
`az config set bicep.use_binary_from_path=false`

Comment: It prevents az from potentially picking up a version that's installed on the agent by default and seperately from then cli.